# MKMapView freezes for about 30 seconds when showsUserLocation = YES

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have an iOS5 app with a MKMapView that completely fills a view controller. In the `viewDidLoad` method, when I set `showsUserLocation = YES` (or through the storyboard), the app freezes for 30 seconds on first run after asking the user for permission to user their current location.

When I set `showUserLocation = NO`, the app works smoothly.

Anyone seen this?